# MassTransit (over RabbitMQ) IServiceBus.Publish(...) hangs unexpectedly

Tags: c#, message-queue, asp.net-web-api2, masstransit

I'm developing web based solution using MassTransit + RabbitMQ. Some time ago I noticed that when I run my integration tests some of them start **unexpectedly** and **very inconsistently** hanging for a very loooong time.
After short investigation I found out that my code hangs somewhere inside *ServiceBus.Publish(T message)* method.

Unfortunately MassTransit documentation and blog posts that I found do not answer what is the reason and how to solve this problem. Hopefully here somebody could help to resolve it.

Here is how I initialize my service bus:

```
ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
      {
        sbc.ReceiveFrom(busAddress);
        sbc.UseRabbitMq(r =>
        {
          r.ConfigureHost(new Uri(busAddress),
            cfg =>
            {
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(busUser) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(busPass))
              {
                cfg.SetPassword(busPass);
                cfg.SetUsername(busUser);
              }
            });
        });

        sbc.UseControlBus();
        sbc.SetCreateMissingQueues(true);
        sbc.SetCreateTransactionalQueues(true);
        sbc.SetNetwork("workgroup");
        sbc.UseBsonSerializer();
        sbc.SetDefaultRetryLimit(2);
        sbc.SetDefaultTransactionTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutSec));

        sbc.Validate();
      });
```

*timeoutSec* value is 10
Service bus is initialized once and registered in Autofac container.

Publishing happens by calling *IServiceBus.Publish(...)* method.

One of the solutions is to  wrap Publish(...) method into Task and use Task.Wait(...) method to enforce timeout but this does not look like a good solution.

I would be really appreciated for any kind of help!

**IMPORTANT UPDATE 2017-01-26:** this question is related to *MT v2*. It seems that MT v3 has similar issue if one forgets "await". My problem is not related to "await" and currently (still) does not have a good solution (as far as I know). I would strongly recommend everyone to migrate to MT v3.

Answer (score 1):

`Send` and `Publish` in MassTransit **v3** are asynchronous by nature. This is how they are designed. You get typical issue when calling async methods without awaiting them - the calling context gets disposed before the task is completed. This is very common. You **have to** await it. MassTransit gives you a utility to call it from synchronous method:

```
TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.Publish(message));
```

Comment: For those, who joined MT community recently it might be kind of obvious that "Send and Publish in MassTransit are asynchronous by nature" but they are not. They became async only starting from v3. If you would read my question carefully you could see that it was published a lot earlier than MT v3 was released (5 months to be precise) and even earlier than TaskUtil was first introduced. Also if you would read topic on Google Groups you would see that my problem is not so "typical issue". Please correct your answer in order not to confuse people who are still using MT v2 and can find this answer

Comment: No need to be defensive here. This is not about MassTransit but about async/await in general, many were here and had the same issue. If you read my answer, it was not meant to patronise you and I realise that you have solved your issues long ago, but we need to help people who will read this question (and answer) today and tomorrow. I updated my answer, mentioning v3 explicitly, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I am pointing out that your answer does not answer original question and explaining why it does not. As I said, without this tiny "v3" remark people who are forced to use v2 will be totally confused and will dig into completely different direction. Thx for update!

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev could you please point me to some good reading regarding how is MassTransit's `TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.Publish(message));` a better alternative than  `bus.Publish(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` 
I found a similar issue and wrapping it in TaskUtil fixed it but I don't understand why awaiting the task in the other way is not enough. Ta

Answer (score 0):

I asked same question on MassTransit Google group and one of the participants pointed me to his question and the only one (at this point of time) solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/masstransit-discuss/oC1FOe6KsAU/VdoTrkcdHS0J

Basically, it seems that the only way to solve my issue is to wrap message publishing code into a Task.